# ORACLE - Find rows which contain words with X number of characters

Tags: sql, oracle

How to search for rows in ORACLE, which contain words with certain amount of characters, let's say 15.
So if the row is "This word has 15 characters - Fifteencharache", that should be brought as a result.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "word"?

Comment: provide some sample data please

Comment: Here is an example to illustrate why Gordon's question is important. Suppose a row contains the string 'two-minute warning' (a common phrase in American football). Does this string contain the word 'two'? Or does it only contain the composite word 'two-minute'? The answer to this question is part of the **requirement**, not part of the **solution** to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to search for (at least) 15 consecutive [word characters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_posix003.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '\w{15}' )
```

If you want exactly 15 characters then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( your_column, '(^|\W)\w{15}(\W|$)' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `regexp_like()`.  For 15 or more characters:

```
where regexp_like(col, '[a-zA-z]{15}')
```

Here is a simple way for space-delimited words:

```
where regexp_like(' ' || col || ' ', ' [a-zA-z]{15} ')
```

You can expand this to more delimiters if you need.